# Products of trig functions and the Thue–Morse sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, products

I was studying transformations of finite products of trig functions into sums, and empirically observed that the following curious identity appears to hold for all non-negative integer $m$: 
$$\prod_{n=0}^m \sin\left(\frac z{2^n}\right)=\frac1{2^m}\sum _{n=0}^{2^m-1} (-1)^{\large t_n} \sin\left(\frac{\pi\,m}2+\frac{2\,n+1}{2^m}\,z\right),\tag{$\diamond$}$$
where $t_n$ is the Thue–Morse sequence.[$^{[1]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence)[$\!^{[2]}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Thue-MorseSequence.html)[$\!^{[3]}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891648/a-nice-formula-for-the-thue-morse-sequence) How can we prove this identity?

Comment: Just as a guess, I suspect there's a relatively straightforward induction proof based on the recursive definition of the Thue-Morse sequence; multiply every term on the right by $\sin(z/2^{m+1})$ and use product-to-sum identities to turn each term into two with the appropriate signs.

Comment: BTW, the product on the left is related to the Fourier transform of the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) and its piecewise-polynomial approximations, and the Thue–Morse sequence is closely related to the same function as well.